# how to get values from a table by providing its id as foreign key in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, first 'customers' and second 'linked'. The following are their columns respectively.

id  |  customer_name | contact_person_name | contact_person_no

id  |  fk_customer_id | item_image

Now, in my views there is a select box where user will select a customer name and I want that customers item_image (from second table) to be displayed below. Any help would be appriciated.

This code is from views

```
<select type="search" name="customer_id" class="form-control 
   @error('customer_id') is-invalid @enderror" name="customer_id" 
   value="{{ old('customer_id') }}" required><option 
   selected>Select Customer to link Item</option>
      @foreach ($customers as $customer)
       <option value="{{ $customer->id }}">{{ $customer- 
       >customer_name }}</option>
      @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: What is a customer_name vs a contact_person_name? Should there be a contact table?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would like to determine the `customers.id` of a `customers.customer_name`, then  look up that `customers.id` in `linked.fk_customer_id` and get the matching `item_image`. This has a flaw: if a `customers.customer_name` is duplicated (two people named John Doe, for example), there will be no way to disambiguate which `customers.id` you would like to return.

Comment: @SebastianSmiley thanks for your comment. Yes, you are correctly understand, but in my laravel views I gave my select tag and options as value="{{ $customer->id }}">{{ $customer->customer_name }}, here I'm displaying customer_name based on customer.id  so there is no chance of duplicate name.

Comment: my search is a dropdown list which contains customer_name, as shown in the code from views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in my views there is a select box where user will select a customer name and I want that customers item_image

There may be several customers with the same name (unless you declared customer_name unique, even then I wouldn't count on that not changing in the future). While you display customer_name, be sure to include `customers.id` as the value. Search by the id.

Then it's a simple [join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp):

```
select linked.item_image
from linked
join customers on customers.id = linked.fk_customer_id
where customers.id = ?
```